# What "IEnumerable<Mat>" mean in C#?

Tags: c#, opencv

When using `calibrateCamera()` of OpenCV in C++, it was used as follows:

```
vector<vector<Point3f> object_points // 3D corner points of the chessboard are stored
vector<vector<Point2f> image_points // 2D corner points of the chessboard found using findchessboardcorner() are stored.
Mat cameraMatrix(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
Mat distCoeffs(1, 5, CV_64FC1);
Mat rvecs, tvecs;

calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, image.size(), cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);
```

However, in C# `Cv2.CalibrateCamera()`, the object_point and image_point parameters are `IEnumable<Mat>objectPoints` and `IEnumable<Mat>imagePoints`.

When storing 3D corner points in a variable declared as `List<List<Point3f>> objpoints` and passing a parameter, I tried casting conversion to `(IEnumable<Mat>)objpoints`, but an error occurred.

I want to know what is the format `IEnumerable<Mat>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know what is the format `IEnumerable<Mat>`

Visual studio should provide the tools to check this. You need to use the debugger to check the actual type of the `IEnumerable`. You should be able to use the object browser to inspect the `Mat` type. A decompiler like dotPeek might also be useful to inspect the implementation details of a type.

In this case it would be reasonable to assume `Mat` describes a matrix of arbitrary size. I would assume one of the matrix dimensions is used for the point coordinates, and the other dimension represents a list of points. When viewed in this way it would contain the same data as a `list<List<Point3f>>`, Both contain `n*m*3` values, just in different ways.

You need to check the documentation on how to convert the data, or write your own converter. A simple cast is probably not going to work since since the datatypes are different.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I think I need to find a way to convert the data in List<List<Point3f>> and put it into Mat.